# Phoenix Framework: mix test fails with argumenterror on new app

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, elixir-mix

So, I'm brand new to Elixir and Phoenix.   I've done a hello world app.   Followed one guy's blog app.   Followed the Phoenix Framework initial steps.   So far, so good.

Tonight, however, I have something new.

Everytime I run mix test, I get the following:

```
hail2skins@elixir:~/workspace/phoenix/test_blog $ mix test
** (ArgumentError) argument error
   :erlang.exit(nil, :normal)
   (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/postgres.ex:55: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.stop/2
   (ecto) lib/mix/ecto.ex:75: Mix.Ecto.ensure_stopped/2
   test/test_helper.exs:4: (file)
   (elixir) lib/code.ex:307: Code.require_file/2
```

Now, I can run mix test in another app on the same server in a different folder just fine.

I have Phoenix 1.03 installed for this app.   But I do see in the other app I have running it's Phoenix 1.02.   In any case, I delete the app, build a new, simple app, run mix ecto.create like the instructions say, then I immediately try mix test and it fails.   Every time I try a new app it fails.   Is this a configuration problem with me -- I'm using Cloud 9, and as I say, everything seems fine on other apps and even this one loads right.

Or is this something new in some way no one has seen before?

It would perplex me less if another app on the same box in a different folder failed too.   But it works fine when I run mix test.   No new app works.

Comment: This is happening to me as well. Very strange -- I've actually worked with Phoenix a fair amount before and this has never happened before. I'm looking into it but we should probably file a bug.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like this is a bug in ecto version 1.0.5. I added the line `{:ecto, "== 1.0.4"}` to the dependencies my mix.exs file, removed deps and _build, and it resolved the issue. I imagine this will get fixed quickly, but sticking to ecto 1.0.4 will solve the issue until then.

Comment: This was it.   I am somewhat proud of myself for stumbling across a bug in a new thing.   I'm sad I had NO IDEA how to fix :).

Comment: Yes. It has also been fixed in Ecto 1.0.6. :)

Comment: Yep.   I tried that too and it worked.   I just decided to play on a bad day :)